# Where does Liferay save its data?

Tags: liferay, portlet

Let's say I'm adding data to different portlets inside of the Liferay Portal. Where is all these data saved to?

Comment: [In database](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Configuration) Liferay comes with default HSQL database and will use it if you didn't specify your own.

Comment: @defaultlocale ok but let's say I wanna show something, everything I get a certain value, or edit some data in a certain portlet. Would this be in there too?

Comment: it depends on a portlet. Google for a particular portlet docs. Some of the portlets that come with liferay store data ( chat messages, news) in liferay database. Some of the data get stored in file system (documents).

Answer (score 3):

Most of the out of the box portlets that Liferay ships with like Blogs, Forums, Wiki, Web content gets stored in Liferay database. You can see the tables and the actual data properly if you have a production ready database configured with Liferay like MySQL or Oracle.

Liferay by default ships with Hypersonic database for quick demo purpose. It save all the information in a file. All the hypersonic related files are saved in "data\hsql" folder inside wherever you have extracted Liferay. You can view the tables using DbVisualizer if you want to see hypersonic db data.

You can also create your custom portlets. Where the data of these has to be stored is completely upto you. You can save the data  in the Liferay's database if you want but that is not mandatory. It's upto you where you want to persist data for the custom portlets

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, this helps me have a better understanding of Liferay and its databases. I am currently using the Plugin Dynamic Data List Display. Do you know by any chance where this plugin saves its data? I am trying to add a progress bar for one of the values and I need to know where to get the data from

Comment: The only data that doesn't go into the database by default is the document library blobs - so you'll find the DDL data in the database as well. The tables start with DDL, but you should not access them directly, rather go through the API to query them. The API is a lot more stable than the database. And if you're ever tempted to write to the database you'll have to deal with dirty caches. So - even when you know where the data is stored, you should avoid reading it from there. Use the API